# SQL Insert Row and copy inserted Auto-Increment id to another column

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment, sql-insert, last-insert-id

I am using PHP and MySQL.

### Goal:

Insert a new row into a table with an auto-increment id column.
While inserting this new row, I would like to copy the new inserted row's auto-increment id # into another column in the same row/entry.
Upon creation, the new entry/row should have the auto-incremented id column and another column with the same number.

My biggest concern:
I need all of this to happen correctly and reliably, even while other transactions from other connections could be taking place on the server.

### So Far

I know only a little about last_insert_id()... and I am afraid of being able to use this reliably for my needs... 
Will I ever run into a situation where the auto-increment id # will have already incremented (due to some other insert query from another connection perhaps) and now I will not get the correct id #? (I did not quite fully understand what it means when the last_insert_id() is given to the client on a **per-connection basis**).

Will last_insert_id() play nice with transactions since they become undefined when the transaction is made to rollback? (If another transaction is rolled back and then I run this script immediately after, will my script return NULL for last_insert_id()?)

I do not understand mysql_insert_id(); how to use it and whether or not it will help me.

So far, I have thought about:

1. INSERT row with `column` set as last_insert_id();
2. INSERT row; UPDATE `column` with SELECT last_insert_id();
3. SELECT last_insert_id(); INSERT row with `auto-increment column` and `column` set as last_insert_id()+1

What happens when I insert a chosen value into the auto-increment column? Will the auto-increment generator start counting from the number I insert? What if I use a value that has been used before (but doesn't exist anymore) and there exists records with id # that come after that value?

Will table or row locking allow me to achieve my desired behavior?

What is the proper/correct way to do something like this?

---

---

### "last_insert_id() is given to the client on a **per-connection basis**"

> last_insert_id is client independent and will return the ID for the
>   last inserted row from that client, therefore you do not need to worry
>   about the case that a user on another connection transacts with the
>   database.

I still do not fully understand what that means...

For a basic SCENARIO:

```
INSERT row where id = 1;
SELECT last_insert_id(); outputs 1

Person A makes a connection to the db; SELECT last_insert_id(); outputs 1.
Person B makes a connection to the db; SELECT last_insert_id(); outputs 1?

Person A INSERT another row where id = 2;

Person A SELECT last_insert_id(); outputs 2?
Person B SELECT last_insert_id(); outputs... 1 or 2??
```

What happens here?

And a SCENARIO that really concerns me:

```
Person A makes a connection with the db;
Person A SELECT last_insert_id(); outputs 1

Person A INSERT row where id = 2;
Person A SELECT last_insert_id(); outputs 2

Person B makes a connection with the db;
Person B SELECT last_insert_id(); outputs 2
Person B INSERT row where id = 3;

Person A SELECT last_insert_id(); outputs 2??
Person B SELECT last_insert_id(); outputs 3??
```

In this case, Person A's last_insert_id() is one count behind.
If this is true, then I will not be able to use my #3 method.

---

Please correct my outputs for me wherever I may be wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to have two columns that will always have the same value, but you can do insert first, get last inserted id and update the table with it.

Comment: @Chibuzo they will not ALWAYS have the same value. as stated, they will have the same values UPON CREATION time. nothing was mentioned about what happens to those fields after creation time.
The reason why I am concerned is that I am not sure if other queries in other connections might interfere with the last_inserted_id in a way that I am not familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [this article](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-last_insert_id.aspx) regarding MySQL `last_insert_id`

`last_insert_id` is client independent and will return the ID for the last inserted row from that client, therefore you do not need to worry about the case that a user on another connection transacts with the database.

Comment: thanks, but that article seems to have the about the same information as the official documentation (except with more examples?).
I am still not fully understanding the full repurcussions of having other connections "transact" with the database.
I have added more to the original in response.

Answer (score -1):

considering you may have multiple access to your DB,

i will do:

1, just insert new row and put `null` into the "another column" let's call it `[autoID_Copy]`

2, then i can run  this:

```
update table set autoID_Copy= autoID where autoID_Copy is null
```

even make it faster you may do
 `where timeInstered < 1 min` or maybe some other filter.

hope this help.

Comment: if you can not(or hard to) get return ID, i suggest you do  a "general update" which records are recently inserted

Comment: but check your PHP SQL execute Functions, maybe you can find a return value.

Comment: sorry but i dont understand any of what you are saying.
I would like to know HOW you are suggesting I should get or return the id. A "general" *SELECT* might "get return ID"... but what is a (and how to do a) "'general update' which records are recently inserted"??
What "PHP SQL execute functions" are you mentioning to check? how are you proposing I find this "return value"??

Comment: "general" update means :  do update without a particular ID. something like  "update table set autoID_Copy= autoID where autoID_Copy is null " is  a general update, usually more many rows could be updated. besides, a particular update usually means only for one row. like  "update table set autoID_Copy= autoID where autoID=123"

Comment: I see what you mean.
That would be similar to my #2, just with potentially more delay on when that column gets updated to the correct value. I would like to put in the column value ASAP to minimize any time where other transactions may happen. These transactions could potentially need the use of this autoid_copied column.