# How to insert id's number in the same row?

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

I'm trying to put the number of `id` in the neighbor column. Something like this:

```
+----+-------------------+
| id | identical_with_id |
+----+-------------------+
```

`id` is `AUTO INCREMENT` and all need is getting id's number when inserting. I can do that like this:

```
INSERT INTO `table_name`
  VALUES( NULL, 
          (SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT` FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
             WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_name' AND
                   TABLE_NAME   = 'table_name')
        );
```

But I don't know it will work all the time. Maybe between *executing that sub-query* and *inserting that row*, a new row (another row) get insert. In this case the number of id will not be the same as neighbor column. Hum? is that possible?

---

**Note:** Please don't tell me: "what do you need this for?"

Comment: @meskobalazs By using a trigger nothing changes. Still I fear between executing my insert query and executing that trigger, another row get insert and then those two column won't be match.

Comment: Yeah, I realized it won't work because of auto increment

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28485117/sql-insert-row-and-copy-inserted-auto-increment-id-to-another-column)?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually everyone sometimes need to do such things. And it's best to not ask for reasons :)

I think you are doing it in correct way but you need to check which MySql engine you are using and make sure that `inserts` are executed sequentially.

Usually insert statement will lock the table and unlock when it's finished. That means your query for retrieving `auto increment` is pretty much safe.

For MySql engine and related settings this post can help you:

[Does a MySQL multi-row insert grab sequential autoincrement IDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481421/does-a-mysql-multi-row-insert-grab-sequential-autoincrement-ids)

For InnoDb:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html

Comment: very and very good ..! This sentence is exactly what I was looking for: *insert statement will lock the table and unlock when it's finished*. upvote

Comment: Look, I don't know English very well. My storage engine is InnoDB. In that link you've attached, is InnoDB safe for my purpose?

Comment: But first check your engine and related settings. As you can see in that post. For InnoDb you need to do some changes..

Comment: I have updated answer with InnoDb link. There you can find steps for setting it up.

Comment: What about using `LOCK TABLES ...` *(I'm using innodb engine)* ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481421/does-a-mysql-multi-row-insert-grab-sequential-autoincrement-ids#8481629`

Comment: I personally don't like this approach because you need manually to say lock and unlock. Sometimes you can forget to unlock and then party is starting :) I don't know. If you like it, and if you are sure that you can always unlock then go for it...

Comment: According to documentation the entire table IS NOT locked unless there are no indexes at all = https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use LAST_INSERT_ID() right after your query.

```
INSERT INTO `table_name` VALUES( NULL, NULL);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @last_id;
UPDATE `table_name` SET duplicate_id_column = @last_id WHERE id = @last_id;
```

Comment: Still I fear between executing my insert-query and executing my update-query, another row get insert and then those two column won't be match.

Comment: Which is why i added the verification WHERE id = @last_id;

Comment: Ah .. Can I write both `insert` and `update` statements in one query?

Comment: @stack You could have a transaction.

Comment: I think you're pretty safe if you execute the queries subsequently. 
mysql docs suggest the same method: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-usagenotes-functionality-last-insert-id.html

If you still have any fears concerning that and it's absolutely crucial to your app, i suggest doing it from the app side, even if the execution time takes a bit longer.